# IE doesnt allow customized browse buttons for input file?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, file-upload, file-io

I'm trying to style my file input, so i ended up having an extra button with some styling, which i will call the "fake browse" button. When a user clicks on the "fake browse", my javascript will automatically click (with jquery .click()) the "actual browse" button for the file input.

It seems to work, since the actual path of the file is pasted on the input file.
When submitting the form, IE automatically clears the file input and the file itself doesn't get uploaded. However, When i click on the "actual browse" button, IE doesn't clear the input file.

But i really dont understand this because when a user click the "fake browse" button, there is an event handler than clicks the "actual browse" button. Help???

Here is what i mean
http://jsfiddle.net/GJJym/

The reason why i had an iframe was that i was trying to make this an ajaxy image uploading process.

Note: This works for FF, chrome, and safari, BUT NOT IE. What the heck!!!

Comment: Welcome to the world of Web Development. Our hero, Sir Developer, will face off against a horde of foes, including but not limited to, the infamous *Internet Explorer*

Comment: why does IE make so many people sad and dissappointed

Comment: because many, many more people than just you have had and continue to have lots of problems with it. To be fair, the latest version, IE9, is a *major* improvement.

Comment: they should with anyone, force, literally force people to update to the newest browser version. no questions ask.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not very practical. Many buisnesses and governments can't update as they have legacy applications that depend on older versions. To update would mess up those apps and also mess up a lot of fine-grain control IT has over the browser usage.

Comment: What's worse than Internet Explorer? Applications that depend on Internet Explorer! 
What's even worse? Applications that depend on specific "old" versions of Internet Explorer!!
Personally, I think system administrators should think hard about throwing these applications out of the window(s)!!! Still, I can imagine that it's not always easy when possibly thousands of people depend on such applications on a daily basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sure why IE isn't behaving here; but if all you're trying to do is restyle the file input control, I suggest you read [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) - essentially you set put a custom styled upload button or text *under* the file input and set the file input's opacity to 0. The user *thinks* he's clicking the custom styled upload button; but he's really clicking the file input. ;)